# Runtime exception, address out of range error MARS MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am working on a MIPS assignment where I have to add up all the digits of a zip code recursively and iteratively. I did it iteratively but when I do it recursively it crashes. I am new to MIPS so I'm not sure what the issue is. This is my recursive function, could anyone point me in the right direction? This is my program:

```
.data
usrMsg: .asciiz  "Give me your zip code (0 to stop): "
iterative: .asciiz "ITERATIVE= "
recursive: .asciiz "RECURSIVE= "
sumMsg: .asciiz "The sume of all digits in your zip code is "
newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    
rec_digits_sum:
addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw $ra, 0($sp) #this is the line with the error

beqz $a0, return0

li $t3, 10
div $a0, $t3

mflo $s2
mfhi $t4
sw $s2, 4($sp)

add $a0, $zero, $t4
jal rec_digits_sum

add $v0, $v0, $s2

exitRecur:
lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $s2, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr $ra

return0:
li $v0, 0
j exitRecur
```

Comment: Where's the `main`?   MARS requires a `main`, and it must exit with syscall #10, not `jr $ra`.  Also, the `main` is useful to properly invoke and provide the parameter to the function.

Comment: Your function is saving the new `$s2` to memory, but it should be saving the old `$s2`.

Comment: Btw, the details of the error message are significant, so if you want help with a crash, should quote the error message literally.

Comment: @ErikEidt I didn't include main because it was too much code. The error I'm getting is: Runtime exception at 0x004000dc: address out of range 0x7fbffff8. How would I save the old $s2 instead of the new one?

Comment: Save it before changing it; typically done in prologue similar to $ra.  Will affect answer correctness, but probably not the crash.

Comment: What instruction is at 0x004000dc?

Comment: Code in `return0:` has no meaning...

Comment: adding 8 to the `$sp` is too much if you store only `$ra`

Comment: extracting regs from the stack should be in reverse order...

Comment: @A.Herlas, the code is doing -8, and using two words of stack space, so +8 is right.

Comment: odd to save on stack later in function and not at the beginning... ;) I'm some kind of master of MIPS.

Comment: @A.Herlas, the code at `return0:` is literally returning with 0 as the return value.

Comment: True, the code is not using the call preserved register properly. (But allocating some stack space in prologue for the function body to use is a valid strategy, though not necessary needed here.)

Comment: Running the code in MARS-MIPS as it is posted will not run, `.text` is missing, there is no `main` label entry (this is not really needed in MARS-MIPS). Once  the `.text` is added it will stop with `Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000`, as it exits from `rec_digits_sum` with `jr $ra` but `$ra` will be zero...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248760/discussion-between-a-herlas-and-erik-eidt).

Comment: I have pointed that out in my first comment @A.Herlas

Comment: mars does not require a main, not even `syscall 10`. qtspim require a main...